# How to find chrome extension in Chrome Web Store by ID

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

In the chrome extension developer dashboard, there is an option to share the extension with tester accounts as documented here:

https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/publish#publishing-to-test-accounts

I know my app's ID but I don't know how to get the "direct link" for my app. I'm assuming it's some sort of hidden store page? Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The direct link to your Chrome Web Store item should be like this: `https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/extension_id` - just replace the `extension_id` with actual id.

Comment: This answer is no longer valid.

Comment: @Qortex if you're still interested, please see my answer below.

Comment: this answer works for me

Comment: Works for me as well

Answer (score 5):

In August 2021, this seems to work:

`https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/extension_id?hl=en-US`

Or you can just type the extension id in the search box on the Chrome web store, it should work even if they change the URL in the future.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work when I just tried. For example for Google docs offline, Id is `ghbmnnjooekpmoecnnnilnnbdlolhkhi`, and it gives nothing with your link. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Google docs offline must be an exception, indeed. Have you tried "normal" (i.e. available on the Google store) extensions?

Comment: Please note that this will not take you directly to the URL of the extension, but it will give you only one search hit, assuming an extension with this id exists.

Comment: ah right, must have tried with non-normal apps only in my tests! Thanks for the tip

Answer (score -1):

Go to Extensions and turn on Developer mode, which should then show you the extension IDs.