# How to identify the Chrome extension breaking a website?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Recently, when I've tried to log into Discord in the Chrome browser, the login page has been completely blank.

If I open the page in incognito mode, the page loads normally, so I know it must be a conflict with one of my extensions. But how do I know which one?

---

Some might suggest: "Open the developer tools console, and look for errors."

I've tried that, and I see the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null
    at HTMLDocument.cookie (<anonymous>:17:58)
    at Object.<anonymous> (3833ed3856c1196040a1.js:41)
    at r (1cb060148fc2158935f3.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (3833ed3856c1196040a1.js:32)
    [...]
```

I then opened the various Javascript files in the stack-trace, but none of them reveal which extension is in conflict. (they're just Discord's own scripts, and "VM..." scripts)

For cases like this (where it's hard to identify the problem extension from the error/stack-trace), what is the most efficient way to identify it?

Comment: disable extensions one at a time until the page displays properly

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way which works pretty well:

1. Install this extension-manager extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/extensions-manager-aka-sw/lpleipinonnoibneeejgjnoeekmbopbc
2. Click the extension icon to open the popup.
3. Right-click the "Enabled" category link at the top of the popup, and press "Open link in new tab". (this way the "popup" panel stays open)
4. Disable the first half of extensions in that list. Do not refresh this list's page! (you need to keep the list there, so you can re-enable the non-problem extensions later)
5. Refresh the original website, and see if the problem still occurs. (ie. [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm))
   A) If it doesn't, the problem-extension is in the just-disabled half, so re-enable half of the extensions you just disabled, and re-execute step 5.
   B) If it does, the problem-extension must be in the still-enabled half, so disable half of those, and re-execute step 5.
6. Once you've narrowed the list down to a single entry, you've found the problem extension. You can now re-enable all the other extensions you had disabled during the search. (since you kept the list's page open, this is easy, since it only shows the list of extensions that were enabled at the start)

Answer (score 0):

You can identify most of the extensions that cause webpage breaks by extension id that is visible in the browser developer window. For example:

1. I noticed that javascript is not working well in my browser
2. I Open up the devtools (f12) while on the website that exhibits that behavior
3. I noticed the error:[image]
4. I copy the id: cmkdbmfndkfgebldhnkbfhlneefdaaip
5. I enter it into google: [image]

Another way is described here: [How to find chrome extension in Chrome Web Store by ID](https://superuser.com/questions/1474705/how-to-find-chrome-extension-in-chrome-web-store-by-id)